# Работа с множествами, Pascal

Tags: pascal

Нужно сделать код. Пользователь вводит строку. Из нее надо сформировать 2 множества. В первом - буквы, которые повторяются в предложении. Во втором - буквы, которые входят единожды в предложение. Когда начинал пытаться делать код, думал что в множествах есть индексы, но оказалось нет. От слова совсем не понимаю как это реализовать без них. Моя задумка была перебрать каждый элемент строки и проверить, если он есть в множестве в котором хранятся буквы которые повторяются в предложении - выход из ифа, если нет, записать его в множество где буквы встречаются единожды. Дальше пока не думал как реализовывать, остановился на этом этапе из-за проблемы

```
var
usetText, repeatedLetters, uniqueLetters : set of string;
input,i: string;
str,n: integer;
begin 
  usetText:=[]; repeatedLetters:=[]; uniqueLetters:=[];
  write('Введите элементы множества');
  readln(input);
  str:=length(input);
  include(usetText,input);
  
  for i:=1 to str do
  begin
    if usetText[i] in repeatedLetters then
    begin
      break;
    end
    else begin
      inlude(uniqueLetters,usetText[i]); 
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Изменил, пересмотрите

Comment: какую версию pascal ты используешь?

Comment: использую PascalABC

Comment: Не нужно удалять сам текст задачи которую решаешь иначе становится непонятен вопрос и ответ. Так же **не стоит** _полностью заменять текст вопроса_ на _"рабочий"_ код - так как в этом случае ответы теряют свою актуальность.

Comment: Если у тебя получился рабочий вариант - лучше добавь его в свой ответ с пояснениями, что же было неверно раньше.

Comment: Добавь свой ответ с кодом, который у тебя работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовый код к заданию выше

```
var repeatedLetters, uniqueLetters : set of char;
input: string;
x: char;
str,i: integer;
begin 
  repeatedLetters:=[]; uniqueLetters:=[];
  write('Введите элементы множества');
  readln(input);
  str:=length(input);
  
  
  for i:=1 to str do
  begin
  if input[i] in uniqueLetters then begin
      x:= input[i];                     
      uniqueLetters:= uniqueLetters - [x];
      include(repeatedLetters, input[i]);
    end
    else begin
     if input[i] in repeatedLetters 
     then 
     else include(uniqueLetters, input[i]);
     end;
  end;
  writeln('Элементы которые встречались неоднократно: ', repeatedLetters ); 
  writeln('Элементы которые встречались единожды: ', uniqueLetters); 
end.
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: что твой код выведет для строки `aaab`?

Comment: Не выведет уникальную b, интересно. Пофикшено, стоило только break убрать

Answer (score 0):

Проверить наличие элемента в множестве можно с помощью [оператора `in`](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/Types/sets.html).

Однако в вопросе проблема в другом.

1. Неверно задан тип множества: так как в множестве хранятся буквы, а не строки, тип должен быть например `set of char`
2. переменная `i` объявлена как строка, однако используется в качестве счетчика цикла. Вместо этого нужно было объявлять ее как `integer`
3. переменная `usetText` не нужна, так как в нее просто сохраняется введенная строка. Вместо этого можно было получать символы прямиком из строки по индексу.
4. сам алгоритм тоже не совсем верный. Решение может быть следующим

   1. если символ в множестве повторяющихся символов - переходим к следующей итерации
   2. если символ в множестве уникальных символов

      1. удаляем из уникальных
      2. добавляем в повторяющиеся
      3. переходим к следующей итерации
   3. если дошли до этого пункта - добавляем символ в множество уникальных.

Comment: До этого у меня стоял тип char и функция readln принимала только 1 элемент из введеных. И насколько я понял мне нужно будет переменную input делать массивом для того чтобы перебирать всё по индексу

Comment: @Дмитрий, `input` и должен остаться строкой. Обращаться по индексу к символу строки ты и так можешь, не надо ничего переделывать.

Comment: Вот что вышло, можете показать ошибки

Comment: @Дмитрий, у тебя не соответствует алгоритму, который у меня в ответе ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Как минимум первый пункт неверно сделан

Comment: @Дмитрий, также непонятно что делает строка `input[i]:= x;` учитывая что ты нигде не заполняешь `x`

Comment: Я уже сделал код, мне и не надо заполнять ```x``` я просто перепутал местами

Comment: @Дмитрий, у тебя неправильный код в вопросе. Если у тебя символ уже повторяется - ты его почему-то в уникальные записываешь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Да и `break` останавливает цикл, поэтому в зависимости от порядка букв можешь разные результаты получать.

Comment: Про то что если символ повторяется и я его записываю в уникальные - бред, пересмотрите код, а если у вас есть альтернатива break, рад узнать

Comment: @Дмитрий, `if input[i] in repeatedLetters then begin` если исходить из названия, ты проверяешь наличие символа в повторяемых. внутри это `if` выполняется `include(uniqueLetters, input[i]);` - что, опять же исходя из названия, является добавлением в уникальные.

Comment: @Дмитрий. для того чтобы перейти к следующей итерации используется `continue`. `break`- потому и `break` - что прерывает цикл.

Comment: @Дмитрий, а, ну да :) `repeat` - это повтор, соответственно `repeatedLetters` - это повторяющиеся буквы :) в то время как `uniqueLetters` - уникальные буквы :) но ты почему-то их наоборот используешь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Дмитрий, но тогда все равно неправильный порядок проверок. Хотя в принципе может и работать

Comment: У меня сделано наоборот, repeatedLetters уникальные.

Comment: @Дмитрий, да, и это запутывает. добавь свой ответ

Comment: Поменял местами